# Is Linus Torvalds a hacker?

Tags: linux, history, terminology

Maybe wrong place for the question, but I couldn't find the answer.
The wiki says he's software engineer and hacker. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds)

Is it true?

I must tell I haven't heard any of the meaning in the answers.
I must quote a book (it's Hungarian, I am not from England, so please correct my spelling):

> It's a frequently asked question that who is a cracker and who is a hacker.
>   In my opinion hacker is someone who is looking for a challenge, 
>   he doesn't want any trouble, so he doesn't do any.
>   He has great knowledge, well prepared, he knows what does he do, and why.
>   (...)

So the meaning of the word hacker isn't so clear.
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Better read [How To Become A Hacker](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html) by Eric Steven Raymond and decide yourself.

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com is not appropriate for 'tude questions.

Comment: @ott I actually think it is an objective question with an objective, technical answer (literally, it has to do with the definition of a word), and reasonably on topic.

Comment: Really more of an etymology question. Good news! There's a stack for that: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/is-the-term-hack-more-positive-or-more-negative

Comment: @goldilocks and sukminder my definition of hacking is to "improve" something that already exists. The Linux kernel was made with the unix kernel in mind, but it was new.

Comment: I didn't thought it's an etymology question. I thought there will be a story or something other...

Comment: I think Linus is the definition of the word. The state-of-art hacker. Since Raymond was mentioned here, read this email: http://lwn.net/2000/0824/a/esr-sharing.php3 to give you a clue... Raymond compares Linus to ability to implement ideas to Ken Thompson. As I said, Linus is strong-opinionated state-of-art hacker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RMS (the founder of GNU and original author of gcc and emacs) has a nice summation of the [etymology of hacking](http://stallman.org/articles/on-hacking.html) including how it came to have a pejorative meaning.  The pejorative one continues to be the most titillating to most people, while the non-perjoritive one has, as RMS says, strong anti-authority overtones, so most people will conflate them, because, "Even if what you are doing isn't wrong, it's still not right."  This has to do with the traditional meaning of the word "hack", which is something done not exactly wrong but not exactly right, either.

In general English usage, a "hack" is someone who is amateurish (or not so good) at something and thus may tend to improvise (due to lack of knowledge and experience); this is also used in programming ("Here's a hack solution..." meaning quickly improvised).  Seems to me this is not coincidence, but "hacker" is more positive than negative, whereas "hack" (noun referring to a person, as in, "He's a hack") is more negative than positive.  The positive angle being: sometimes that hack (noun referring to the quickly improvised solution) turns out to be a *genuine breakthrough.*  Probably this was more or less normative on the frontiers of computer science in the late 20th century -- even the biggest talents would have been regularly hacking away at stuff no one completely understood.

So as RMS says, a hack may be a somewhat ingenious or unpredicted solution, and a hacker someone who solves problems in ingenious or unpredictable ways. Linus is famous for linux, which is really a hack on (or of) unix, in all senses (presumably at first it was "amateurish").  But he didn't steal source code from Bell Labs or anything to do it.

Answer (score 11):

Absolutely. To cite [RFC 1392](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1392#appendix-H):

```
   hacker
      A person who delights in having an intimate understanding of the
      internal workings of a system, computers and computer networks in
      particular. The term is often misused in a pejorative context,
      where "cracker" would be the correct term.  See also: cracker.
```

And as so correctly addressed by the good Mr. [@Vincent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21670/vincent), *["cracker"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracker_%28pejorative%29)* suffers the same fate as a [pejorative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pejorative) in the non binary realm.

Especially in media or the like, they should use terms like *"computer-hacker"* or *"computer-cracker"* instead of *hacker* and *cracker*, and use them respectively correctly according to context. Though for some it
is a *lost battle* – for yours truly it is not.

Comment: you might want to be more specific about the cracker part: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracker_(pejorative)

Comment: Don't think of it as a *lost battle*, think of it as a *missed boat*.  If a boat is missed, obviously somebody caught it or it would still be here...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, he is. Hacker has several definitions, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker

Comment: So if I create a program, am I a hacker in a certain sense??

Comment: I have a book, that uses it as something like cracker (but the book exactly defines the word)

Comment: @radl: A novice with little understanding of what they do can write a program. Though it is for many a stepping stone to be both a true hacker or cracker. Put it like this: *Am I a great painter because I painted a picture?*, *Am I a carpenter after hammering a nail?* ...